# HQL query to determine unique values of foreign key

Tags: hibernate, join, group-by, hql

I have two tables, File and FileType, of this form:

File
id | Filename | etc

FileType
FileId | FiletypeName | etc

and I'm trying to write a query in HQL which will return the attributes of a given file, including its type, if uniquely identified.

So far so simple, just join the tables on id = fileId.

My problem is that FileType is not necessarily uniquely identified for a file, there may be more than one entry in the filetype table with the same FileId.

I need to return one row per File, regardless of how many entries there are in FileType.

I'm not very bothered what I get back in the FileType field if there are multiple identified types, so long as it's predictable and no exceptions get thrown.

I'm not even sure if this is possible using an HQL query, so if anyone can see another way to do it I'm open to suggestions, in fact even just confirmation that it can't be done this way would be helpful, as I'm not very confident with HQL yet.

thanks for reading

Comment: if there are multiple FileTypes for each File, is there any criteria to identify the one true Filetype to return?

Comment: or can you write a cleanup task to get rid of the unwanted filetype records?

Comment: Firo, thanks for looking and the suggestion. Unfortunately there is no way to know which (if any) of the reported types is correct. Our system generally is pretty good at identifying files and will return just one per file, but in rare cases poorly formed files get several possible types returned.

Comment: how does your classes look like and can they be changed?